# Next.js Webviewer Reference Error on build, window is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am creating a website where I have a pdf viewer inside my page imported dynamically.
the code runs locally without errors, but during the "npm run build" command I find the following error:

```
> Build error occurred
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\GustavoMorilla\MyProfile\node_modules\@pdftron\webviewer\webviewer.min.js:1:224)
    at Object.g7Pv (C:\Users\Gustavo Morilla\MyProfile\.next\server\pages\resume\viewer.js:121:18)    
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\Gustavo Morilla\MyProfile\.next\server\pages\resume\viewer.js:23:31)
    at Module.vRHl (C:\Users\Gustavo Morilla\MyProfile\.next\server\pages\resume\viewer.js:134:76) {  
  type: 'ReferenceError'
info  - Collecting page data .npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE }
```

viewer.js code:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import WebViewer from "@pdftron/webviewer";

const Viewer = () => {
  const viewer = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {   
    WebViewer(
      {
        path: '/lib',
        initialDoc: "/pdf/GustavoMorilla.pdf",
      },
      viewer.current
    ).then(function (instance) {
      instance.setTheme("dark");
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>      
        <div className="Viewer">  
        <div className="header flex justify-between">          
          <a>Resume</a>
          <a className="text-sm">You can download the file on "Settings" button</a>         
        </div>    
        <div className="Webviewer" ref={viewer}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Viewer;
```

resume.js code:

```
import SiteLayout from "../../components/SiteLayout";
import React from "react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
const Viewer = dynamic(() => import("../resume/viewer.js"), { ssr: false });

export default function Resume({ resume }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <SiteLayout>    
      <div className="main w-screen">                         
          <Viewer />     
        </div>               
      </SiteLayout>
    </div>
  );
}
```

should be something related with the SSR or lifecycle... i dont know.

Comment: sounds like you have a server side (isomorphic) (SSR) implementation - when this code runs on the server, it has no window object - you need to prevent the code running this part on the server - I think ```React.useEffect``` runs on server, if my memory serves

Answer (score 0):

`window` object doesn't exist on the server side, use conditional rendering to solve the problem.

```
import SiteLayout from '../../components/SiteLayout'
import React from 'react'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const Viewer = dynamic(() => import('../resume/viewer.js'), { ssr: false })

export default function Resume({ resume }) {
  return window ? (
    <div>
      <SiteLayout>
        <div className="main w-screen">
          <Viewer />
        </div>
      </SiteLayout>
    </div>
  ) : null
}
```

Comment: We dont have a definition for window.. when i try this code we get the reference error.